# Error compiling eigen_msg on OSX 10.9

Tags: ros, homebrew, mavericks, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build Hydro on OSX Mavericks by following the guide on the wiki. I am using an up-to-date homebrew, which got me this far. After several days of tracking down and fixing other compiler errors, I'm finally stuck on `eigen_conversions` and in particular `eigen_msg`.

`./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install` fails with an error having to do with `implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::allocator<void>'`. The full `make` output is below. Any ideas? Is this an issue relating to clang on OSX? Do I need to update some include paths?

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'eigen_conversions'
==> Building with env: '/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/eigen_conversions'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/eigen_conversions'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/eigen_conversions.dir/src/eigen_msg.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/src/eigen_msg.cpp:31:
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:37:
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h:51:
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout.h:71:89: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::allocator<void>'
   typedef std::vector< ::std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension_<ContainerAllocator> , typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind< ::std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension_<ContainerAllocator> >::other >  _dim_type;
                                                                                        ^
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h:72:16: note: in instantiation of template class 'std_msgs::MultiArrayLayout_<std::allocator<void> >' requested here
  _layout_type layout;
               ^
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:97:8: note: in instantiation of template class 'std_msgs::Float64MultiArray_<std::allocator<void> >' requested
      here
  if (m.layout.dim.size() != 2)
       ^
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/message_forward.h:33:28: note: template is declared here
template<typename T> class allocator;
                           ^
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/src/eigen_msg.cpp:31:
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:37:
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h:51:
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/std_msgs/MultiArrayLayout.h:71:118: error: 'rebind' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template
   typedef std::vector< ::std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension_<ContainerAllocator> , typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind< ::std_msgs::MultiArrayDimension_<ContainerAllocator> >::other >  _dim_type;
                                                                                                                     ^~~~~~
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/src/eigen_msg.cpp:31:
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:37:
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h:74:41: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::allocator<void>'
   typedef std::vector<double, typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind<double>::other >  _data_type;
                                        ^
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:97:8: note: in instantiation of template class 'std_msgs::Float64MultiArray_<std::allocator<void> >' requested
      here
  if (m.layout.dim.size() != 2)
       ^
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/message_forward.h:33:28: note: template is declared here
template<typename T> class allocator;
                           ^
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/src/eigen_msg.cpp:31:
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:37:
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h:74:70: error: 'rebind' following the 'template' keyword does not refer to a template
   typedef std::vector<double, typename ContainerAllocator::template rebind<double>::other >  _data_type;
                                                                     ^~~~~~
In file included from /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/src/eigen_msg.cpp:31:
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:103:18: error: member reference base type '_data_type' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
  if ((int)m.data.size() != e.size())
           ~~~~~~^~~~~
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:104:11: error: member reference base type '_data_type' (aka 'int') is not a structure or union
    m.data.resize(e.size());
    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/src/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h:108:13: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
      m.data[ii++] = e.coeff(i, j);
      ~~~~~~^~~~~
7 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/eigen_conversions.dir/src/eigen_msg.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/eigen_conversions.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'eigen_conversions': 
  Command '/Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4' returned non-zero exit status 2
 
Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/eigen_conversions && /Users/sagar/workspace/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4
 
Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112866/error-compiling-eigen_msg-on-osx-10.9/) by [sagargp](https://answers.ros.org/users/10206/sagargp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-12-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue you are seeing is caused by a problem in the **roscpp_core** upstream package and has been disused and fixed in https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/pull/15. Unfortunately an updated release of this package has not been created for hydro, so you will have to make the change to package by hand.

cd <path/to/ros/workspace>/src/roscpp_traits/include/ros
curl https://raw.github.com/ros/roscpp_core/8292898d4a90ecc8cf3d42c5ce4e51e14b02a8db/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_forward.h -o message_forward.h

Here <path/to/ros/workspace> is the path of your ros workspace.

---

Originally posted by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) with karma: 316 on 2013-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sagargp](https://answers.ros.org/users/10206/sagargp/) on 2013-12-26**:
Awesome! Thank you. This worked. Except now I'm running into other, unrelated problems. Currently stuck with "theora_image_transport/Packet.h not found". Any ideas?

**Comment by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) on 2013-12-27**:
I have not had a problem similar to that, sounds like something related to the image transport is broken.